# File Integrity with ant deployment and hudson ci

Tags: ant, hudson, rsync

I just like to ask how I can check the file structure and their permission after ant deployment. I want to integrate it with Hudson CI. I am thinking of calling the ant deployment first then use rsync command on linux to check the file integrity. Is this the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you'd like to deploy the file from Hudson using ANT and then subsequently call rsync? (If rsync reports no difference, the file must be good?)

My thoughts:

- Why not use rsync to do the deployment in the first place?
- A more traditional way to check file integrity is to use a file checksum. Calculate the checksum on the remote system and compare that to the local checksum on Jenkins.